# What is this indicator in ADK eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adk

Quick question about ADK and Eclipse, what does this indicator at the bottom right of eclipse that looks like a progress bar that never goes away?  Mine usually says "81 of 161" and bounces around but never goes away.

Sorry I know this is a very basic question, but I'm curious what its for.

Cheers,

[image]

Comment: You could upload the image elsewhere and link to it. It sounds like this is memory usage within the IDE.

Comment: memory usage makes sense, here is a link to a screen clip: http://i1101.photobucket.com/albums/g436/pabsCDN/screen1.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically displays the heap status; and the trash icon is for garbage collection. If you click on the icon then the system will run the following codes

```
System.gc();
System.runFinalization();
```

To turn it off, preferences -> general -> uncheck the "show heap status" checkbox.